How do you pronounce the word "promptly"?
I have a question about the pronunciation of the word "promptly."
I've checked several sites, but it seems there are two variations.
One pronounces the word with the "T" as "prompt-ly," and the other with a silent "T" as "promp-ly."
Should it be promp-ly, prompt-ly, or promptly with a unaspirated t sound?
Which is the correct way to pronounce it, and is there a rule for words like this? Thank you so much in advance.

For BrE I would say "unaspirated t sound" is correct but the difference between this and a silent T is very subtle (with a silent B). This may even be a north / south thing in England (like the southern unaspirated T in butter, etc.)

My intuition about my own (American) pronunciation accords with @timchessish’s “unaspirated t sound.” But I wouldn’t be at all surprised to learn that when speaking fluently (and thus at speed) I was in the promply camp. One’s intuition about one’s own diction is not always reliable.

Merriam-Webster has 3 versions, with both /p/ and /t/ optional. Is that where you looked? Lots of words have multiple pronunciations, you just have to deal with that as a learner. Try and be consistent with similar words (e.g. tempt, soundly) but don't worry too much.
